# selecting the next and previous radio_button_tag in jQuery (.js.erb file)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, radio-button

I have a list of elements and each of these elements has three radio button with unique IDs like "deal5" and "deal6".. each one of these radio button is in its own form_tag.

I want to 
-select the previous and next radio_button_tags if the middle one is checked and uncheck them
-select the two next radio_button_tags if the first one is checked and uncheck them
-select the two previous radio_button_tags if the last one is checked and uncheck them

here is my html.erb file

```
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="go-to-deals">
    <div class="deals-wrapper">
        <% @deals.each do |d| %>

        <div class="deal">
            <ul>
                <li><%= d.value %></li>
                <li><%= d.background %></li>
            </ul>

            <%= form_tag("deal_status", :remote=>true, :id=>"deal" + d.id.to_s) do %>
            <ul style="list-style-type:none;">

                <li> 
                    <%= hidden_field_tag 'pending_deal_ids[]', d.id.to_s %>
                    <%= radio_button_tag '', d.id.to_s, d.state == "pending", :class => 'radio' + d.id.to_s %> <%= "pending" %> 
                </li>
                                </ul>

            <%end%>
        <%= form_tag("deal_status", :remote=>true, :id=>"deal" + d.id.to_s) do %>
            <ul style="list-style-type:none;">

                <li> 
                    <%= hidden_field_tag 'won_deal_ids[]', d.id.to_s %>
                    <%= radio_button_tag '', d.id.to_s, d.state == "won", :class => 'radio' + d.id.to_s %> <%= "Won" %> 
                </li>
            </ul>

            <%end%>
        <%= form_tag("deal_status", :remote=>true, :id=>"deal" + d.id.to_s) do %>
            <ul style="list-style-type:none;">

                <li> 
                    <%= hidden_field_tag 'lost_deal_ids[]', d.id.to_s %>
                    <%= radio_button_tag '', d.id.to_s, d.state == "lost",  :class => 'radio' + d.id.to_s %> <%= "Lost" %> 
                </li>
            </ul>

            <%end%>
        <% end %>
```

Comment: You mention an .js.erb file, where is it? Also, it is bad practice to have .js.erb files, you don't want to dynamically render js files using erb or the like.

Comment: @Mosselman this is the js I have right now and it's not working 
`$(".radio_<%=@deal_id%>").change(function(){
 $(":radio").not(this).attr({"checked": false});
});` I added a dynamic class to each button tag .. ill update my question

Comment: Radio buttons are not 'checkable'. You are confusing them with checkboxes. Also where did you read the syntax `$(':radio')`?

Comment: I read it somewhere here in stackoverflow, but I can't find the link now.

Comment: Can you please make a jsfiddle with the html and the javascript that you are using? That way it is easier to test your code and fix it, for you AND for us. Also, are you using the developer console of your browser at all?